# php preg_match '/' with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, routes

I'm matching routes, so If I have a string

`"/teacher/jkDfl"`

and I want to check if it starts with

`"/teacher/"`

My newbie approach is hoping this evaluates to true

`preg_match("/^/teacher//", "/teacher/jkDfl")`

But I think the issue is all the `'/'` characters, and looking around nothing popped out at me. I probably need to work on my google-fu, but I figure this is simple for someone with xp in regex.

Cheers!

Comment: The takeaway from all the answers below: whatever you decide to use as your pattern delimiter, you'll need to escape it with a backslash if it actually occurs within your pattern.

Comment: So do you mean whatever delimiter I choose, if I want to use it in the pattern I must escape it?

Comment: Because you don't have a # in your pattern. #^/te#acher/#" would need escaping for the # in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delimiters are somewhat arbitrary, so, the often used `#` delimiter would work:

```
preg_match("#^/teacher/#",....
```

If you're very fond of `/`'s, you can escape them with `\`'s:

```
preg_match("/^\/teacher\//",....
```

... or let PHP do that for you (good for user provided literal strings):

```
preg_match("/^".preg_quote("/teacher/","/")."/",...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use # as regexp delimiter.

```
preg_match("#^/teacher/#", "/teacher/jkDfl")
```

You could also capture the various parameters (e.g. jkDfl) with regexps, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

In this case:

```
if (preg_match("#^/teacher/([^?]*)#", $url, $gregs))
{
    $teacher = $gregs[1]; // "jkDfl"
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: change the delimiter or escape the literals.

Different delimiter:

```
preg_match("%^/teacher/%", "/teacher/jkDfl");
```

Escape literals:

```
preg_match("/^\/teacher\//", "/teacher/jkDfl");
//or
preg_match("/^" . preg_quote("/teacher/", "/") . "/", "/teacher/jkDfl");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
preg_match("/^\/teacher\//", "/teacher/jkDfl")
```